# Issue when trying to save each item in a list to a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to save each item in a list to a text file, however, I keep coming across an error.

This is an example of my code:

```
example_list = ["1", "2", "3"]

for i in example_list:
    with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(i)
```

When I run this and then open file.txt all that's in there is "3".

Comment: Swap the with statement with the for loop. You're currently reopening the file every iteration, and "w" clears the file every time you open it.

Comment: You are opening the file in write mode ("w") every time you iterate through the loop. The "w" mode will create or overwrite the specified file (subject to permissions etc)

Comment: You are getting onpy last string because you gave atttibute as write mode. so it overwriting you have to give "a+" instead of "w" so it will append instead of overwrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question

```py
example_list = ["1", "2", "3"]
for i in example_list:
    with open("file.txt", "a") as f: # change mode to append
        f.write(i)
```

Little better solution

```py
example_list = ["1", "2", "3"]
with open("file.txt", "w") as f: # open file once
    f.write("".join(example_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use append mode to write to next time so it will not overide existing file content